# Проблема с определением части текста в ячейке

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. У меня есть задача найти в определенных совпадения части текста, но к сожалению функция срабатывает если найден целый текст.
Пример: ищем в ячейке `АБВ`, в ячейке содержится `123, АБВ, 456` - ноль реакции, если в ячейке `АБВ` - то все находит.

Код следующий:

```
$result=mysql_query('SELECT virtuemart_product_id  FROM  virtuemart_products WHERE "Стена" in(product_parametr1, product_parametr2, product_parametr3)');
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможно, что такие инструменты, как Elasticsearch, Sphinx и т.д. для вашего текущего уровня будут сложноваты (*хотя лучше сразу привыкать к "хорошему"*), но можно посмотреть в сторону [полнотекстового поиска](https://habrahabr.ru/post/40218/)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
SELECT virtuemart_product_id 
    FROM virtuemart_products 
    WHERE product_parametr1 LIKE "%Стена%" 
        OR product_parametr2 LIKE "%Стена%" 
        OR product_parametr3 LIKE "%Стена%"
```

Answer (score 0):

> ищем в ячейке АБВ, в ячейке содержится 123, АБВ, 456 - ноль реакции, если в ячейке АБВ - то все находит.

В подобных случаях надо не сравнивать, а именно что проверять на вхождение. Возможные варианты проверки:

```
WHERE field LIKE '%АБВ%'
WHERE INSTR(field, 'АБВ')
```

> Код следующий

Возникает подозрение, что одно из трёх проверяемых полей в точности равно требуемому литералу. Тогда:

```
WHERE "Стена" = product_parametr1
   OR "Стена" = product_parametr2
   OR "Стена" = product_parametr3
```

Но если ищем вхождение литерала как подстроки в одно из трёх полей, я бы рекомендовал использовать:

```
WHERE INSTR(CONCAT(product_parametr1, product_parametr2, product_parametr3), 'АБВ')
```

Всё равно индексы по полям использоваться не будут, а так будет выполняться конкатенация и один поиск (пусть и по более длинной строке), а не три отдельных поиска, имхо так будет чуток побыстрее.

Comment: Благодарю, этот метод подошел идеально.

А как теперь можно сделать чтобы сравнивалось два разных совпадения?
например вот так:
SELECT virtuemart_product_id  FROM  ak89e_virtuemart_products WHERE  INSTR(CONCAT(product_parametr1, product_parametr2), "Стена" AND INSTR(CONCAT(product_parametr1, product_parametr2), "Пол"
Мне нужно получить id именно того товара, в котором есть несколько совпадений.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: уже сделал, спасибо )

Comment: возник попутный вопрос. как можно в запрос вставить тело запроса, которое задано в переменную? например:
$spisok = 'product_parametr1, product_parametr2, product_parametr3, product_parametr4, product_parametr5';

$result=mysql_query('SELECT virtuemart_product_id  FROM  ak89e_virtuemart_products WHERE  INSTR(CONCAT(".$spisok.'")

Comment: тоже сделал) 
проблема была в неправильном закрытии скобки